# Adding product image programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, gallery

below is my code, i have array of images i want to set first image of array as main , base and thumb image but it does not works .also just 3 images shows in gallery instead of 4

issue

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(1);


$importDir = 'bulkimages/101/';

$productsData = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg');

$k=0;
foreach($productsData as $fileName){
    $k++;
    $productSKU = '111';
    $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        echo $filePath;

            $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);

        $ourProduct->save();
        echo "done ";
    } else {
        echo $productSKU . " not done";
        echo "<br>";
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a bit. Try that.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(1);


$importDir = 'bulkimages/101/';

$productsData = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg');
$productSKU = '111';
$ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);

$k=0;
foreach($productsData as $fileName){

    $k++;
    $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;

    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        echo $filePath;

        if ($k == 1)
            $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
        else
            $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array(), false, false);

        echo "done ";
    } else {
        echo $productSKU . " not done";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

$ourProduct->save();
```